# BLE: WriteValue of GattCharacteristic doesn't get called

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I followed the tutorial from [The Bluetooth Technology for Linux Developers Study Guide](https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/the-bluetooth-for-linux-developers-study-guide/) (I skipped the 5th guide because I'm doing a gatt server), and everything worked fine until I got to **Handling Characteristic Writes**.

(Also, I am using a Raspberry PI 4 Model B)

In nRF Connect I have the following in the logs:

```
Writing request to characteristic e95d93ee-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8
Data written to e95d93ee-251d-470a-a062-fa1922dfa9a8, value: (0x)68-65-6C-6C-6F, "hello"
"hello" sent
```

so the data should have been sent.

`sudo btmon` gives the following:

```
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 14               #129 [hci0] 82.584227
      ATT: Prepare Write Request (0x16) len 9
        Handle: 0x0019
        Offset: 0x0000
          Data: 68656c6c6f
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 14               #130 [hci0] 82.585053
      ATT: Prepare Write Response (0x17) len 9
        Handle: 0x0019
        Offset: 0x0000
          Data: 68656c6c6f
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5    #131 [hci0] 82.814773
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 1
```

so the data was indeed received. Though I don't understand why it says Prepare Write Request instead of just Write Request.

bluetoothd with -nd flag and `tail -f /var/log/syslog` gives the following:

```
Jul 28 09:20:45 raspberrypi bluetoothd[820]: bluetoothd[820]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() (chan 0x1bb9dd0) ATT PDU received: 0x16
Jul 28 09:20:45 raspberrypi bluetoothd[820]: bluetoothd[820]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() Prep Write Req - handle: 0x0019
Jul 28 09:20:45 raspberrypi bluetoothd[820]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() (chan 0x1bb9dd0) ATT PDU received: 0x16
Jul 28 09:20:45 raspberrypi bluetoothd[820]: src/device.c:gatt_debug() Prep Write Req - handle: 0x0019
```

but there is no reaction using `sudo dbus-monitor --system`, and nothing either in the program output terminal.

Do you have any Idea where the problem might come from?
(I tried reinstalling nRF Connect twice already, so I think the problem is from somewhere in the Raspberry, but is it from bluez? from dbus? or somewhere else?)

---

After reinstalling bluez, and not solving anything, I tried with an old samsung tablet, and it works. So it appears my assumption was wrong and the problem could be from my phone.

Comment: What is your question specifically? By the way, the link you provided is broken.

Comment: Thank you, i corrected the link and tried to be cleared with my question.

Comment: Don't you see any "Execute Write Request" in the log?

Comment: No, the log I copied here are the only lines that appeared when I pressed the send button  on nRF Connect
but I made some more research, and it appear I am not the only one with a phone posing problem when using BLE